# How can I use websocket onMessage on different pages?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, websocket

I call onMessage when I initialize websocket, but if I go to the next page, how can I reset the callback of onMessage? I tried to redefine onMessage on a new page, but this will cause me to receive duplicate messages,just like:

```
page1 code:
ws = new WebSocket(url)
vuex.setter.ws = ws
ws.onMessage = function(e) {
    // do something
}

page2 code:
ws = vuex.getter.ws
ws.onMessage = function(e) {
    // do other thing
}
```

Comment: centralize `ws.onMessage` to one location (vuex store) and handle all possible messages in one place.  different pages can listen to changes in the store and react accordingly